# How to create a dict using Ansible inventory

Tags: dictionary, ansible, inventory

I need bit of help in creating a dict of host names and ip address out of a Ansible inventory.

Here is my inventory:

```
web:
  hosts:
    Webserver1:
      ansible_host: "10.10.10.10"
      Environment: "Dev"
      location: DC1
    Webserver2:
      ansible_host: "10.10.10.11"
      Environment: "Dev"
      location: DC1
    Webserver3:
      ansible_host: "10.11.10.10"
      Environment: "Dev"
      location: DC2
```

and I want to run a playbook on my local Ansible control machine to create a dict as follows

```
host_dict={Webserver1:10.10.10.10, Webserver2:10.10.10.11, Webserver3:10.11.10.10}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demo:

```
- name: a play that runs entirely on the ansible host
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
   host_dict:
    Webserver1: 10.10.10.10
    Webserver2: 10.10.10.11

  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ host_dict }}"
```

In YAML, if it does not start with a `-` then it is a dictionary key, otherwise it's a list. See more advanced examples here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/dict.html

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to hard code the dict in my play, I want to read it from my inventory and create a dict.

Comment: So with "out of the inventory" you mean deriving a dictionary from the inventory for later usage in a playbook?

Comment: exactly I am going to use this dict in different places in my plabyook. Just a note I am not running my playbook against hostgroup "web" and running on local ansible control machine. IF